# How to display Bootstrap Autocloseable alert message on asp.net button click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How to display Bootstrap Autocloseable alert message on asp.net button click?

Code as follows:

```
 <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-block org"
        Style="margin-top: 0px" OnClick="btnLogin_Click showalertmsg();" ValidationGroup="Login" />
</div>
```

closeable code using javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showalertmsg(message, alerttype) {

        $('#alert_placeholder').append('<div id="alertdiv" class="alert ' + alerttype + '"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>' + message + '</span></div>')

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#alertdiv").remove();

        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

I called function name"showalertmsg" on asp button click it gives error?
error gives as follows while compiling

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected
```

Comment: you are missing a semicolon after $('#alert_placeholder').append .....

Comment: it give compile error : Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected @sajad

Comment: did you add the semicolon ??

Comment: yes @SajadKaruthedath

Comment: can you post the button click script also

Comment: it gives error at line  onClick of button , the compile error as follow :Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected @SajadKaruthedath

Comment: OnClick of button above script is called .@SajadKaruthedath

Comment: you show me that calling function please

Comment: did you use OnClientClick="showalertmsg();"

Comment: It work ,but didnt show alert msg

Comment: did you have a div with id="alert_placeholder" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't call javascript fuction like this

```
OnClick="btnLogin_Click showalertmsg();"
```

But

use `OnClientClick="showalertmsg();"`

and also call return false at the end to stop postback

```
function showalertmsg(message, alerttype) {

        $('#alert_placeholder').append('<div id="alertdiv" class="alert ' + alerttype + '"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>' + message + '</span></div>')

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#alertdiv").remove();

        }, 5000);

return false;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't display alert msg !@Sajad

Comment: please update your question with the html part like the div with id="alert_placeholder" and all relavent codes..so that we can answer

Comment: @Rohan: try my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Issues in the asp.net button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-block org"
        Style="margin-top: 0px" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="Login" OnClientClick="showalertmsg(); return false;" />
```

Comment: It doesn't display alert msg ! @Aravind

Comment: in OnClientClick you need to return false otherwise it will postback.

Comment: How to return false??@Aravind